Path is a directory: cp returned EISDIR (./cache is a directory (not copied)) ./cache
I am facing the following error. It is using NWjs and the command I am using to build is:
npx nwbuild ./* --mode=run --version=latest --flavor=sdk

I am using volta node version manager and the nodejs version is set according to NW.js version I have:

SystemError [ERR_FS_EISDIR]: Path is a directory: cp returned EISDIR (./cache is a directory (not copied)) ./cache
    at getStatsForCopy (node:internal/fs/cp/cp:200:11)
    at async build (file:///media/Data/newApp/new%20Desktop%20app/node_modules/nw-builder/src/bld/build.js:42:5)
    at async nwbuild (file:///media/Data/newApp/new%20Desktop%20app/node_modules/nw-builder/src/nwbuild.js:212:7) {
  code: 'ERR_FS_EISDIR',
  info: {
    message: './cache is a directory (not copied)',
    path: './cache',
    syscall: 'cp',
    errno: 21,
    code: 'EISDIR'
  },
  errno: [Getter/Setter],
  syscall: [Getter/Setter],
  path: [Getter/Setter],
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2024-07-06T10:03:48.544Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(message)]: '[ ERROR ] 2024-07-06T10:03:48.544Z Path is a directory: cp returned EISDIR (./cache is a directory (not copied)) ./cache'
}

Node.js v22.2.0

Here is the directory structure:

Please help!

Change "nw": "^0.89.0" to "nw": "0.89.0-sdk". Delete node_modules, package-lock.json, and yarn.lock. Run npm i && npm i -D nw-builder && npm pkg set scripts.start="nw ." && npm start. Refer to the README in nw-builder GitHub for usage. You'll likely want to create a build.js file and and a script in the package.json to run "build": "node build.js". Try playing around with it. If you get stuck you can post your package.json. Or for nw-builder specific questions, ask on their github issues. https://github.com/nwutils/nw-builder/issues
